# Node position based on two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

I'm trying to position nodes with tikz to draw a schematic.
I would like to position nodes containing explanations text stacked below each other and at a specific x shift from the related word.

[image]

My first idea was to positon the explanations nodes against each other with :

```
\node (otherexplanations) at ($(explanations.south east)+(4mm,0)$) {..};
\node (anotherserie) at ($(otherexplanations.south east)+(4mm,0)$) {..};
```

but I don't have the correct left shift with the related word.

**My question is :**

Is it possible to set a **node position based on two nodes** and adjust the x and y shifts independently ?

For exemple, positionnig the node *anotherseries* at 5mm below the *otherexplanations.south* node, and at 10mm left from the *PHRASE.left* node.

---

I'm aware I could use absolute coordinates, but I would like to make it adaptable to any amount of text in nodes on several schematics.

Comment: Perhaps you want to anchor the two nodes as `\node[ancohr=north west]`?

Comment: Or simply \node[below right]...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt] (explanations) {THIS IS MY EXPLANATION};
  \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt] (otherexplanations) at ($(explanations.south east)+(4mm,0)$) {First text};
  \node[anchor=north west,inner sep=0pt]   (anotherserie)      at ($(otherexplanations.south east)+(4mm,0)$) {Second text};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With the `positioning` library the anchors are set automatically so we can just do `below right=0mm and 4mm of <other node>`. (Or set `node distance=0mm and 4mm` and just use `below right=of <other node>` of course.)